# Firebase and Thread 1

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When ever I add my firebase code I get the autonomous:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {      THREAD 1 SIGNAL SGABRT
```

I've taken out all my Firebase related code from the View Controller script, and it works smoothly with no errors. I am using swift 3 and have tried updating my pods, but no success there either.  This is the code that I've decided has to be causing the error.

```
    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

That is at the begging of my script with all my other declarations. And...

```
        ref.child("Agent1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.FnameA1 = value?["Fname"] as? String ?? ""
        print("\(self.FnameA1)")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Which is where I am trying to grab data from the database and set my local variable (FnameA1) as a string from my database.  Although I get no error while compiling I know the error has to be there. I will show the format of my database below in case the error is from how I grab data from it.

```
{
  "Agent1" : {
    "Edition" : "Standard 17",
    "Fname" : "L.",
    "Lname" : "James",
    "Ovr" : 95,
    "Pos" : 3,
    "Price" : 1000000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to use de Firebase reference before Firebase has been configured. In your log you should see a message similar to this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.'
```

You can fix this by making the variable first, and setting the value (the actual reference) later.

```
var ref : FIRDatabaseReference?
```

And then in your function:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("Agent1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    self.FnameA1 = value?["Fname"] as? String ?? ""
    print("\(self.FnameA1)")
```

Comment: Although that did fix the original error, I now get:     2016-12-11 19:11:42.652: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"                   When using the function shown there.  As I am new to Firebase I would understand if there is a easier way to set my local variable as the Fname value shown in the json part above.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This error is common when using the simulator. Go to your project and then to the capabilities tab. Enable keychain sharing to fix this error and you should be good to go. Your approach for getting the Fname seems perfectly fine 

Comment: @Peter can you mark the question as answered if this solved your problem?

Comment: @Peter no problem. If you need any more help let me know!